# Angular routing: Conditional route with library import

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-library, angular-route-guards, angular-lazyloading

**TL;DR**

How can I have a conditional route with conditional import of the corresponding Angular library during build time, depending on a feature flag in the environment file?

**Background**

I'm having a route configuration that lazy loads an Angular library / module:

```js
{
    path: 'wishlist-management',
    loadChildren: () => import('@mycompany/thelibrary').then(m => m.TheLibrary),
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    canLoad: [AuthGuardService],
}
```

The requirement is, that it should only load the library, **if it is enabled with a feature flag** in the environments file. For that, I've implemented an `AuthGuardService` with the `canLoad` method:

```js
  public canLoad(
    route: Route,
    segments: UrlSegment[],
  ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.isFeatureEnabled(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extractedUrl.toString());
  }
```

This `canLoad` method is also provided in above mentioned route configuration.

However, supposing the feature flag is false and therefore `canLoad` returns `false`, and that therefore also `@mycompany/thelibrary` is not installed as npm dependency in the project, I'm getting an error:

```
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mycompany/thelibrary' in '/home/user/projects/myproject/frontend/app/node_modules/@mycompany/someotherlibrary/fesm2020'
```

which is as expected, since `canLoad` will only load the chunk file at runtime, but is already building it during build time.

However, how can I achieve a fully conditional route and import of the corresponding library / module already in build time, only if the corresponding feature flag is true? It should only try to import the library if the feature flag is true.

---

I have found [a blog](https://dev.to/madhust/conditionally-lazy-load-modules-in-angular-4l5l) post solving this problem by passing `null` in the route configuration and then manipulating the `loadChildren` dynamically on router event hooks. But this feels hacky and not the way to go for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to completely remove any reference to your library from code before build. Use `fileReplacements` configuration in `angular.json` file. We will replace this file with a dummy based on the build environment.

1. Create a separate file for loading the route.

   `src/environments/thelibrary-routes.ts`.

   ```js
   export const thelibraryRoutes = [{
     path: 'wishlist-management',
     loadChildren: () => import('@mycompany/thelibrary').then(m => m.TheLibrary),
     canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
     canLoad: [AuthGuardService],
   }]
   ```
2. Then in your routes load it as

   ```js
   import { thelibraryRoutes } from 'src/environments/thelibrary-routes.ts'
   // Other imports

   const routes = [
     // Other routes
     ...thelibraryRoutes
   ]
   ```
3. Then create a second dummy file.

   `src/environments/thelibrary-routes.empty.ts`

   ```js
   export const thelibraryRoutes = [];
   ```
4. Now this is the cool part. Edit your angular.json file and under `build.configurations` add a new one for when your module should be excluded (or if it fits your case, do it in the `production` configuration, if **you want to exclude your module in production for example**). Under your desired configuration, add a new entry to `fileReplacements` list like this:

   `angular.json:`

   ```json
   // Other JSON
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                { 
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                },
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/thelibrary-routes.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/thelibrary-routes.empty.ts"
                },

              ],
   // Other JSON
   ```

   Note that the first entry in `fileReplacements` is already there. Only add the second one.

You can use this approach to include/exclude routes depending on your build configuration. Optionally you can set the routes inside the `environment.ts` file itself if you don't want to create a new file for the routes, in which case you wouldn't need to edit `angular.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy loaded modules, as name indicates, are LOADED at runtime, not conditionaly bundled (or not) into the package. You cannot (nor you should) exclude it from the build process by removing it from npm dependencies. (at least not without custom preprocessing)

Comment: *Are also not directly loaded at runtime, only when absolutely needed, OR if the `preloadingstrategy` is set to `PreloadAllModules`

Comment: @Antoniossss Thanks for your reply. My goal is to only ship that module as part of my JS bundle, if the corresponding route is enabled. This can already be determined during the build, it's not something dynamic - just a static configuration setting in the environment file. Therefore, having it conditionally included in the bundle is exactly what I want. Even if lazy loaded modules don't fit for my approach like you say, I'm still searching for a solution. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I understand that what is your need and there is NO build in mechanism to do it as far as I am aware of. You would have to have 2 separate source codebases and switch between them. In one of them you would include routing to your module and in another you would not. It is doable using architect i think, but I am not sure if this is something you want to go after.

Comment: What if you would actually build your bundle and just remove chunk with your module? Potentially it could work as every code required to lazy load your module is already bundled into the main, so as long as you will not try to load it up, you should be fine (404 in worst case scenario i think)